# Sending an array of bytes filled with special characters

Tags: c#, sockets, encoding

I am making a chat program that has a client and server side, in a WPF project.
I am trying to send a username and a message from client to server, I use this data class.
With english characters, there's no problem, but once I try special characters in the username or message it all goes to hell. What can be the problem?
I've tried increasing the size of the array but that obviously didn't help
[The problem visualised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zC9G.png)

```
byte[] byteData = new byte[1024]

public Data(byte[] data)
        {
            //The first four bytes are for the Command
            this.cmdCommand = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

            //The next four store the length of the name
            int nameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);

            //The next four store the length of the message
            int msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

            //This check makes sure that strName has been passed in the array of bytes
            if (nameLen > 0)
                this.strName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12, nameLen);
            else
                this.strName = null;

            //This checks for a null message field
            if (msgLen > 0)
                this.strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12 + nameLen, msgLen);
            else
                this.strMessage = null;
        }

        //Converts the Data structure into an array of bytes
        public byte[] ToByte()
        {
            List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

            //First four are for the Command
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

            //Add the length of the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Length of the message
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strMessage.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Add the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName));

            //And, lastly we add the message text to our array of bytes
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage));

            return result.ToArray();
        }

        public string strName;      //Name by which the client logs into the room
        public string strMessage;   //Message text
        public Command cmdCommand;  //Command type (login, logout, send message, etcetera)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure. But based on the code you posted, it seems you misunderstand the relationship between your text (the `string`) values, and the length of the data as it's sent.

First, make sure you understand that TCP (if that's the protocol you're using…since you're sending passwords, hopefully it is, and you've wrapped the socket in an SSL stream) has no built-in message framing. It's entirely up to you to achieve that. The fact that you are including lengths in the data suggests you already understand this, but I want to emphasize it just in case.

Second, the lengths you are sending are the *character* lengths of the `string` values. This is only the same as the number of bytes that are sent when the `string` contains only ASCII characters. The UTF8 and ASCII encodings overlap for the first 128 characters, with those character having single-byte values in both encodings…for all other characters, UTF8 uses two or more bytes. This means that when you use *"special characters"*, the length value you're sending is not the same as the actual length in bytes of the data you're sending.

Most likely, you need to fix the sending code to look more like this:

```cs
public byte[] ToByte()
{
    List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
    byte[] nameBytes = strName != null ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName) : null,
        messageBytes = strMessage != null ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage) : null;

    //First four are for the Command
    result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

    //Add the length of the name
    if (strName != null)
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(nameBytes.Length));
    else
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

    //Length of the message
    if (strMessage != null)
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(messageBytes.Length));
    else
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

    //Add the name
    if (strName != null)
        result.AddRange(nameBytes);

    //And, lastly we add the message text to our array of bytes
    if (strMessage != null)
        result.AddRange(messageBytes);

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

This will get the encoded text prior to having to send the data lengths, and then use the lengths of the text as it's actually encoded in the message, rather than the text's character length (which has no direct relationship to the length as the data appears on the network).

Note that you will need to double-check the receiving code to ensure that it's correctly decoding this new format. It may already be, but you didn't post it, so I can't say whether it does or not.